# Handlebars not defined in gulp-handlebar

Tags: javascript, templates, npm, gulp, handlebars.js

What EXACTLY do I need to install to get this working? I have a structure that looks like this

- index.html
- gulpfile.js
- templates/

  - frontPage.html
- scripts/

  - main.js
  - handlebars.js

In my index.html I have (I included jQuery in head)

```
<body>
  <div id="front-page"></div>
  <script src="build/scripts/templates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="build/scripts/handlebars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="build/scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="build/scripts/svg-to-inline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

and in my gulpfile.js I have

```
// Handlebars
gulp.task('templates', function(){
  gulp.src('templates/*.html')
    .pipe(handlebars())
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
      namespace: 'GD.templates',
      noRedeclare: true, // Avoid duplicate declarations
    }))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/'));
});
```

which in turn gives me template.js as follows

```
this["GD"] = this["GD"] || {};
this["GD"]["templates"] = this["GD"]["templates"] || {};
this["GD"]["templates"]["frontPage"] = Handlebars.template({"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
return "... html content not relevant ...";
},"useData":true});
```

which I then try to use in my handlebars.js like

```
"use strict";
// var data = { title: 'This Form', name: 'Joey' };
var frontPage = GD.templates.frontPage;
console.log(frontPage);
console.log($('#front-page'));

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#front-page').html(frontPage);
});
```

the problem is that I get a Handlebars not defined from my template.js row 3. I've tried npm install handlebars but that didn't work. I'm not sure what I'm missing but I'd love some help on this one.. It's driving me insane.

Comment: I included `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.4/handlebars.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in my index.html and changed my package.json to include `dev-dependencies {handlebars: 4.0.4}`, installed `npm install handlebars` and changed my gulpfile to `.pipe(handlebars({handlebars: require('handlebars')}))` and only then I got it working. feels like I've been using some extra stuff I don't need but I can't figure out what I actually need and what I don't anymore. brain malfunction overload etc.